# LINQ - merge 2 lists but with specific order

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to merge 2 lists into one list, however, it have to be in special order.

For example, I have a list of type A:

{ A, A ,A ,A ,A, A .... }

And also a list of type B:

{B, B, B , B ....}

And desired result should be like this:

{A, A, B, A, A, B, A, A, B}

The merge should take the 2 items from list A, and then 1 item from List B.

One thing to note is, in case of one list gets empty, fill all the rest items with the second list's items.

I trying to find an elegant way to do it with LINQ.

Heres my code, but it's a bit long and I hope there is a better way to do it via linq:

Thanks a lot.

```
    public IList<PersonBase> Order(IList<Person1> people1, IList<Person2> people2)
    {
        if (people1.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return people2;

        if (people2.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return people1;

        List<PersonBase> orderedList = new List<PersonBase>();

        var people1Count = 0;
        var people2Count = 0;

        while (people2Count < people2.Count || people1Count < people1.Count)
        {
            var people1ToAdd = tags.Skip(people1Count).Take(1).ToList();
            people1Count = people1.Count();
            orderedList.AddRange(people1ToAdd);

            if (people1Count >= people1.Count)
            {
                orderedList.AddRange(people2.Skip(people2Count));
                break;
            }

            var people2ToAdd = people2.Skip(peopleCount).Take(2).ToList();
            people2Count = people2.Count();
            orderedList.AddRange(people2ToAdd);

            if (people2Count >= people2.Count)
            {
                orderedList.AddRange(people1.Skip(people1Count));
                break;
            }
        }

        return orderedList;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your code please.

Comment: Is there a property on A and B that can be used to determine the sort order, like `instanceOf_A.SortOrder`?

Comment: Why is the list being filled that way? The way you've written those two lists with the ellipses at the end indicates they could each have an arbitrary number of items so I don't understand what determines the output format.

Comment: What do you mean by "ratio of the sequence items per list"? Do you mean number of items in `A` devided by number of items in `B`? Do both lists always contain only the same values (either `A` or `B`), or can a list contain a mix of say `A` and `B` and possibly `C`?

Comment: Added code for illustration of what I did

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty horrible code but does what you want it too. Basically we keep track of each lists index and have an `int` that keeps track of which list to use to populate the result array.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };

int list1Counter = 0;
int list2Counter = 0;

int arraychecker = 1;

int[] resultArray = new int[list1.Count + list2.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (list1Counter < list1.Count && list2Counter < list2.Count)
    {
        if (arraychecker == 1 || arraychecker == 2)
        {
            resultArray[i] = list1[list1Counter];
            list1Counter++;
            arraychecker++;
        }
        else
        {
            resultArray[i] = list2[list2Counter];
            list2Counter++;
            arraychecker = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (list1Counter < list1.Count)
    {
        resultArray[i] = list1[list1Counter];
        list1Counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        resultArray[i] = list2[list2Counter];
        list2Counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something similar, but I', looking for "LINQ" solution.
But thanks any way!

Comment: @RomShiri if it does what you want why does it matter?

Comment: @RomShiri I think you need to think about readability rather than just going for a linq solution because it's "elegant"

Comment: Perhaps you right. I hoped there is much more elegant way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the index for each item and then order by that index.

```
var mergedList =
    listA.Select((item, index) =>
        new { Index = index / 2 * 3 + (i % 2), Item = item})
    .Concat(listB.Select((item, index) =>
        new { Index = i * 3 + 2, Item = item}))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Index)
    .Select(x => x.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Or write a method. This is more efficient, since it doesn't need to sort; It just runs through each list once.

```
static IEnumerable<T> Alternate<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceA, IEnumerable<T> sourceB) {
    using (IEnumerator<T> eA = sourceA.GetEnumerator(), eB = sourceB.GetEnumerator()) {
        bool aHasItems = true, bHasItems = true; 
        while (aHasItems || bHasItems) {
            if (eA.MoveNext()) yield return eA.Current;
            if (aHasItems = eA.MoveNext()) yield return eA.Current;
            if (bHasItems = eB.MoveNext()) yield return eB.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do:

```
string[] test1 = { "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A" };
string[] test2 = { "B", "B" };
string[] result = test2.SelectMany((value, key) => test1.Skip(key * 2).Take(2).Concat(test2.Skip(key).Take(1))).ToArray();
        result = result.Concat(test1.Skip(result.Length / 3 * 2).Take(test1.Length - result.Length / 3 * 1)).ToArray();
```

This will take 2 from array1 then 1 from array 2 then add whats left of the longer one. Output:

```
AABAABAAAAAAAAA
```